# Running a .NET program from a network share

Tags: winforms

I have a Windows Form app which I developed and deployed to a network share.  The users of my program have shortcuts on their desktop to the exe file.  If I need to upgrade the program (deploy new bits), I cannot do this while the users have the files open (exe is running on their machine).  What kind of options do I have?  I'd like to minimize the changes to the shortcuts from a maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our workplace, we have a wrapper application which checks the server, then copies any files which are newer on the server to the local machine, then launches the app from the local machine.  We then created a shortcut to this wrapper on the desktop, and made it look like it was the actual app.

This would take a one-time change to each machine to set up, but you could probably write something to automate it based on a check of the path to the executable when it is launched.

Comment: That's definitely a different approach than what I had.  I like it.  I understand that I will probably have to change the shortcuts at least once.  I'd just prefer not to have to change the shortcut every time we have a new release.

Comment: It works really well for us, provided we actually remember to update the server with the latest version of every DLL.  We also augmented it with a timer in the app which checks whether there's a new primary executable on the server and pops up a "There's a new version" message every so often.  If we just update the dlls and not the executable (which, ideally, only knows how to launch forms from other dlls), then there's no prompt, and it just updates on next launch.